# What is the difference between request.GET['q'] ,request.GET('q'),and request.GET('q',)

Tags: python, django

What is the difference between request.GET['q'] ,request.GET('q'),and request.GET('q',).Thanks

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q=request.GET['q']
        books=Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return render(request,'search_results.html',{'book':books,'query':q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('please submit a search term')
```

Comment: You don't have either of the second or third versions in that code.

Answer (score 1):

`if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']` it just check for dictionary contains that `q` key. But it looks ugly. You can do it more pythonic:

```
q = request.GET.get('q') # returns None if q not in GET
if q:
    do your logic
```